# Do you need to restart the daemons whenever you modify the cluster properties in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

Say by default the replication factor is 3 and I would like to know if we modify the replication factor to 2, do we need to restart the hadoop daemons for the changes to be in effect?

If so then are there any specific reason why it has been made like that?

Other way around what sort of issues can come up if say the configuration would be applied without requiring a restart of the hadoop cluster?

Answer (score -1):

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.18.3/hdfs_shell.html

The definition of the following command:

```
setrep
Usage: hadoop fs -setrep [-R] <path>

Changes the replication factor of a file. -R option is for recursively increasing the replication     factor of files within a directory.

Example:

hadoop fs -setrep -w 3 -R /user/hadoop/dir1
Exit Code:

Returns 0 on success and -1 on error.
```

**Replication factor** can be changed for a specific file so clearly restarting of daemons is not required. The whole purpose of the **replication factor** is that if one of the **data nodes** is down and the value of the **replication factor** for certain files falls below the required value they are automatically being **rereplicated**.

Comment: I am sorry if I made it look confusing, I wanted to understand if you modify any properties in below files
- **core-site.xml**
- **hdfs-site.xml**
- **mapred-site.xml**
- **yarn-site.xml**

Do you need to restart the daemons? I am trying to understand if that is the case, any specific reason as why they have been designed like that.

Comment: One such situation I can think of is, lets say the replication factor is *3* which is set in the xml.Let a mapreduce be running with default setting (takes 1 hour to process).

Now say I would change the replication factor to *2* (*globally* and not specific to that MR job and would take like 5 mins to completion). 
Say another Map Reduce which is already running with the RF of 3 would be affected.(Had it been designed in a way where change in properties would be in effect without restarting the daemons).